Set zIndex of Views in different View-Hierarchy
I have 4 Views: A, B, C and D
A and B are inside the VStack C.
C and D both are in a ZStack.
I want A to be beneath B, therefore both are in a VStack.
The problem is, that I want to set the zIndex of A to 1, B to 3 and D to 2. The zIndex only applies to Views inside the same View-Hierarchy. But if I put A, B and D into the same ZStack, then A and B are no longer below each other. If I put D inside the VStack C, then it is not on top of A and B any more...
How can I solve this puzzle?
I want to achieve this, because in my case, D is an overlay that should detect click events on everything but on B (which is a pop-up-menu). A is a button to show the menu B. Clicks on D are supposed to close the menu B. But the items in B should still be clickable.
Here is an example:
struct Test: View {
    @State private var isMenuVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack { //C
                Button(action: { //A
                    isMenuVisible.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Open Menu")
                })
                
                if (isMenuVisible) {
                    Rectangle() //B
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .overlay {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("is clickable!")
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Menu-Button")
                            })
                        }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
            if (isMenuVisible) {
                Color.red // D
                    .opacity(0.6)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isMenuVisible.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

If I put the if-Statement inside the ZStack, then it works, but then not the entire screen is covered.

Please include a [mre]

Ok I added an example

1. You can use this hierarchy instead:
VStack  
  |---OptionButton
  |---ZStack
        |---Dismisser
        |---Menu


2. If it's necessary to overlap on Option-Button:

by fix/known sized button or dynamic size observer

struct Test: View {
    @State private var isMenuVisible = false
    //@State private var dynamicHeight = 50.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Color.clear // make ZStack wider
            
            Button {
                isMenuVisible.toggle()
            } label: { 
                Text("Open Menu")
            }
            .frame(height: 50)//dynamicHeight = observeHeight
            .border(.green, width: 1)
            
            if isMenuVisible {
                Color.red //Dismisser
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isMenuVisible.toggle()
                    }
                
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("is clickable 1!")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Menu-Button-1")
                    })
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("is clickable 2!")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Menu-Button-2")
                    })
                }
                .border(.green, width: 1)
                .padding(.top, 50)//.padding(.top, dynamicHeight)
            }
        }
    }
}

for observing live high of any view
.overlay(
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Color.clear.onAppear {
            dynamicHeight = geo.size.height
        }
        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global)) { _ in
            dynamicHeight = geo.size.height
        }
    }
)


So the solution is to put the views all inside the ZStack and then add padding to the menu items, instead of letting the VStack handling the padding.

@ykasur Indeed. There are two additional solution as well. If the first two are not suitable for you, I can share, but it makes little UI load.

Non Swifty ways
1. Make Dismisser very large:
Since Dismisser will not visible &
It's Clickable even if out of bound of Option-Button.
VStack {
    Button {
        isMenuVisible.toggle()
    } label: { 
        Text("Open Menu")
    }
    .overlay(
        ZStack {
            if isMenuVisible {
                Color.red //Dismisser
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    .frame(width: 1500, height: 2500) // alternate
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isMenuVisible.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    )
    .border(.green, width: 1)
    
    if isMenuVisible {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("is clickable 1!")
            }, label: {
                Text("Menu-Button-1")
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                print("is clickable 2!")
            }, label: {
                Text("Menu-Button-2")
            })
        }
        .border(.green, width: 1)
    }
    
    Spacer()
}
//.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
//.scaleEffect(10)//100


2. Make Multiple Dismisser 
The location of second dismisser may change depending on the situation.
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            isMenuVisible.toggle()
        } label: { 
            Text("Open Menu")
        }
        .overlay( ZStack {
            if isMenuVisible {
                dismisser
            }
        })
        .border(.green, width: 1)
        
        
        if isMenuVisible {
            VStack {
                Button { } label: {
                    Text("Menu-Button-1")
                }
            }
            .border(.green, width: 1)
        }
        
        Color.clear
    }
    .background( ZStack {
        if isMenuVisible {
            dismisser
        }
    })
}
    
//@ViewBuilder // if isMenuVisible is handled here
var dismisser: some View {
    Color.red
        .opacity(0.5)
        .onTapGesture {
            isMenuVisible.toggle()
        }
}

